# How to solve a linear algebra problem of finding a linear combination as a problem in matrix algebra of solving a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Linear Algebra problem:

Write the vector $w = \left[ \matrix{ 1 & -2 & 5 \cr} \right]$ as a linear combination of the vectors
$$
u_1 = (1, 1, 1), \ u_2 = (1, 2, 3), \ u_3 = (2, -1, 1)
$$

Expressing $w  = x u_1 + y u_2 + z u_3$ and solving for $x, y, z$, we obtain
$$
x = -6,  y = 3, z = 2.
$$

How can the same problem be solved using matrix algebra as a problem of solving linear equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We define the column vectors
$$
v_1 = u_1' = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\
      1 \\
1 \\
\end{array} \right], \ \ 
v_2 = u_2' = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\
      2 \\
3 \\
\end{array} \right], \ \ 
v_3 = u_3' = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
      2 \\
      -1 \\
1 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

We form the matrix
$$
A = \left[ \matrix{v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \cr} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 2 \\[1mm]
 1 & 2 & -1 \\[1mm]
 1 & 3 & 1 \\[1mm]
\end{array} \right].
$$

We define
$$
b = w' = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\
-2 \\
5 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

Solving the linear system of equations
$$
A \mathbf{x} = b,
$$
we obtain the unique solution
$$
x_1 = -6, \ \ x_2 = 3, \ \ x_3 = 2
$$

Thus, the given problem in linear algebra can be solved by posing it as a problem in matrix algebra of solving a system of linear equations using the standard methods of linear system solvers. $\ \ \ \blacksquare$